# Add WordPress Core CSS into editor-style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, tinymce, editor

Here is my current issue : I am using a custom child theme (from Parabola, [Cryout Creations](https://www.cryoutcreations.eu/), last version), but it seems that the `editor-style.css` file is not up-to-date. Rather than rewriting everything, I would like it to contain every css used on the front-end, so TinyMCE looks as close as the published page/article (this is important).

In order to do that, I have created a new `editor-style.css` file in my child theme, so it overrides the not-up-to-date file. So far, it includes the `style.css` file from my theme, but it lacks a lot of CSS from WordPress Core : the ones written on line 60 on the index file : http://nouveau.domaineloupia.com.

So, how to add this “core CSS” to my `editor-style.css file` ? And would it be the best way to do this ? I have seen many stuff talking about the add_editor_style function, but I do not know if I could use it to do what I want nor how.

Thanks for reading so far, and thank again in advance for any help you could provide !

Comment: Why not just copy and paste the CSS from the original CSS file into the new CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `@import url("YOURCORECSS.css");` in the top of your `editor-style.css' file?

But that tends to slow down your pages.

Comment: Yeah, but I do not know such a file. From the index page, the "core CSS" looks like [this](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/629207css.png)

Comment: Usually there isn't a core Wordpress CSS theme. I do not want to discount taht you say there is one I might be wrong. But [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS) shows the Wordpress classes.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I am just looking for a way to include the "default" WordPress classes into the TinyMCE editor (throught the editor-style.css file, because I only know that way), and trying not to copy/paste the default css (in case of WordPress Core upadte)

Comment: so then find that sheet in your WP install and append the way I showed :)